# How to check if JavaScript object was created in the current window or another window?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an object `OtherObj` that was created in a window `OtherWindow` which is different from the current one `ThisWindow`:

```
const ThisWindow = window;
const ThisObj = ThisWindow.history;

const OtherWindow = window.open();
const OtherObj = OtherWindow.history;

console.log(ThisObj instanceof Object); //true
console.log(OtherObj instanceof Object); //false
console.log(OtherObj instanceof OtherWindow.Object); //true, but this works only if I already have a reference to OtherWindow
```

Now imagine if I **only** have a reference to `OtherObj`, is there a way to get the window that was used to create it? Maybe there is a property on `OtherObj` that holds a reference to the window it was created in?

I'm currently trying to come up with a cross-window way to use the `instanceof` operator. As you can see in the code example, `[variable] instanceof Object` will return `false` if the variable is pointing to an object created outside of the current window.

Some of you might say to just use `OtherObj instanceof OtherWindow.Object` (which returns `true`), but that only works if I already have a reference to `OtherWindow`. My question is assuming I do not already have a reference to `OtherWindow`.

Is there a property somewhere on `OtherObj` that points to the window that created it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:**

```
const OtherWindow = OtherObj.constructor.constructor('return window')();
```

---

**Long answer:**

Because most things are an object in JavaScript you can access their constructor with `Object.getPrototypeOf(ObjectIn).constructor`, from the objects prototype. But because of the prototype chain `ObjectIn.constructor` has the same effect.
And because that constructor is a function, its constructor is `Function`. And once we have `Function` we can access everything from that window with `Function('return ...')()`.

So an implementation to get `Function` could be as follows:

```js
const getFunction = (ObjectIn) => {
  // Get ObjectIn's constructor
  const ObjectInConstructor = ObjectIn.constructor;
  // Get Function
  return ObjectInConstructor.constructor;
};

const getObject = (ObjectIn) => {
  const Function = getFunction(ObjectIn);
  return Function('return Object')();
};

const OtherWindowObject = getObject(OtherObj);
const OtherWindow = getFunction(OtherObj)('return window')();
```

Because StackOverflow's HTTP headers don't allow `open()` I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lusc/pt0qydhm/) to demonstrate.

Comment: Very clever! Couldn't the whole thing be simplified down to the following: `const OtherWindow = OtherObj.constructor.constructor('return window')();`